# Two-terminal current source review

Tags: led, current-source, review

When testing an unknown-voltage LED panel, I always connect it to a bench power supply with a series resistor, and increase the voltage until it lights up.

Because I’m not sure about the voltage and I don’t want to blind myself, it can take a while to find the right voltage (sometimes they need up to 100 V), so I decided to design and build a two-terminal current source that could replace the resistor.

My requirements are simple: it has to work with at least 100 V, a few mA (I usually test with less than 5 mA), and survive reversed polarity. I found a nice chip that, I think, could work here: [LR8](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005399B.pdf) from Microchip; it looks like a high-voltage version of LM317.

U1 with R1 would work as the current source, and bridge BR1 would make sure it would work no matter the polarity. C1 is a foil capacitor, and C2 and R1 are SMDs in 1206 packages.

[image: Schematic]

There is a mistake on the schematic: C2 should be 1 µF, which is the minimal output capacitance according to the datasheet.

Comment: Just to double-check: does your bench power supply have a current limit adjust?

Comment: C1 will cause a turn-on current spike of potentially multiple amps. Is that okay for your LEDs?

Comment: Yes, but it has a 10 mA resolution, which is too high to look at an LED panel. I always set the current limit to some low value in case there is a short and the current panel needs less voltage than the previous one, so LED will probably be okay with that.

Comment: You should update your drawing to show that the load is connected in series with R1.  Like in figure 3-4 of the datasheet.  This will eliminate the C2 discharge question.

Comment: It isn't; the load is connected in series with this whole module. I'm just thinking about adding a dummy load resistor, exactly like in figure 3-4.

Answer (score 2):

Can any LED you might test survive C1 being charged to supply voltage thorough it?

Can an LED you might test survive 100V+ reverse voltage plus C1 being charged through any breakdown if you get the polarity reversed? That would be even harder on the junction(s).

I would think a somewhat higher voltage and a series resistor would be a good idea.

Incidentally, this is also the problem with using the current limit on the bench power supply, but worse since they often have a fairly large capacitor on the output. They are not a constant-current supply when first connected, they are more of a capacitive-discharge welder.

Answer (score 2):

The capacitors in your circuit will cause large current spikes at turn-on.

Here are two potential solutions. I did not add the diode bridge to make it bipolar, so please pretend it's there.

[image]

The one on the right is a depletion MOSFET used as current source. For example, [DN2540](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DN2540%20B060313.pdf), DN2530... These are normally-ON devices, with negative threshold voltage, so they will conduct with Vgs=0V, similar in behavior to a JFET. Adding a resistor makes a current source, which is a really simple and bulletproof 2-component circuit.

Current depends on the FET's threshold voltage, which is not accurately specified, so a bit of experimentation is in order to find the exact resistor value.

The depletion FET is a bit of an exotic part but it gives a very simple circuit, since it requires no external bias. In addition there is little capacitance, a few tens of pF, which means the turn-on current spike will be low. LED capacitance should be enough to absorb the small current spike. This allows connecting the circuit when the power supply is already energized: its current limiting action is almost intantaneous.

In case of extra paranoia, an inductor can be added (with a damping resistor in parallel) to reduce the current spike even further. I don't think it will be necessary.

[image]

---

The one on the left uses no special hard to find parts, it's the usual two transistor current source. Feedback through Q1 controls the MOSFET to keep voltage on R2 equal to Vbe. Thus the LED current is Vbe/R2, in this case about 1mA.

You'll need a MOSFET with SOA and dissipation corresponding to your goals, which should be easy to find. For example, IRF610. Q1 can be pretty much any NPN since its Vce is limited to the MOSFET's gate voltage. If the load (LED) is not connected, no current will flow through the FET, so Q1 will not limit gate voltage, so D2 will do so and protect the FET gate. R1 biases Q1, the value should be chosen for a current of, say 100µA at low voltage,  to limit dissipation at high voltage.

R3 C1 may be added to form a snubber to avoid oscillation in case of very long wires.

The two transistor current source circuit has higher capacitance (mostly due to the larger MOSFET) and it also has one gotcha: if the biasing resistor R1 is connected to the supply, but the LED is not connected yet, then Q1 will set the FET's Vgs to the maximum in an attempt to conduct the design current. This means the FET is fully ON at the moment the LED is connected, and a huge current spike will flow until Q1 manages to bring Vgs down.

Here's an illustration: on the right, the current source is biased by V3, then voltage is applied later to the LED.

[image]

So like the design in your question, this one should be connected to the LEDs first, then power applied.

---

This one is not a good current source, because there's a 100k resistor in parallel, so current will vary slightly with voltage. But it looks good enough for the purpose of testing LEDs. Replacing the FET with a smaller BJT having much lower capacitance produces a much smaller current spike at startup too.

[image]

Comment: A depletion FET isn't that exotic if you look at JFETs instead of MOSFETs. While there probably aren't any common silicon JFET that would meet the voltage requirements, you can get silicon carbide JFETs that are capable of withstanding well over a kilovolt, and this would be a situation where I'd consider using one. Might not be the cheapest solution, but you can't beat the simplicity of two components.

Comment: That's true, depletion FETs aren't that hard to find. Didn't consider JFETs due to voltage requirements, but I forgot about SiC. That said I think the 2 transistor quasi-CCS (at the bottom of the answer) makes a nice "junk parts bin" design.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the one I'd go with if I didn't have a bunch of SiC JFETs laying around from a previous project--which I expect most people don't.

Comment: Quite the luxury "junk parts bin" 

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of old school (you should readily find them on the web -- Supertex for sure has appnotes on this -- now on Microchip's site) methods that provide limited current while also working equally well regardless of orientation of the 2-terminal `device`. These just use JFETs (higher voltage ones like 2SK373 or could use SiC JFETs?) or NFETs (like the LND150.)

Something like these:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT94YA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the JFETs, the current will be what it is. But with the NFETs the current can be tweaked in with \$R_1\$. I set it to a nominal \$1\:\text{mA}\$ producing value. But when you get the parts you can work out the final details for it.

The NFET circuit's behavior will look about like this:

[image]

Works the same regardless of which way you flip it. So no worries. (\$V_{_\text{GS}}\$ for both devices is kept low.)

Here's Supertex's [AN-D11](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN-D11.pdf) on the topic, for example.

You will need to worry about the LED orientation with respect to the voltage supply orientation. I probably would not want to start with \$100\:\text{V}\$, preferring to take it up in steps, if possible. But I'm not sure of your past methods, which you know far better than I. So I will let you figure out if this is workable, or not.